# Google cast youtube embed videos

Tags: ios, uiwebview, google-cast, ytplayerview

Hi guys i am working on an app that fetches youtube video ids from my server & play those videos using `YTPlayerView` framework.

Now, i want to stream those videos using `GoogleCast`. Some where i saw that google cast not works on UIWebView. Basically `YTPlayerView` is also built on top of `UIWebView`.

My question is, is it possible to stream embed videos using Google cast SDK from `YTPlayerView` in iOS app ?

Here is the code how am loading video using `YTPlayerView` :

```
var params = ["controls":2, "playsinline":0, "autohide":1, "origin":"http://www.youtube.com","autoPlay":1, "showinfo":0, "modestbranding":0, "rel":0]
self.videoPlayerView.loadWithVideoId(movieId, playerVars: params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to checkout the [YouTube Helper Library for iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

> The youtube-ios-player-helper is an open source library that helps you
>   embed a YouTube iframe player into an iOS application. The library
>   creates a UIWebView and a bridge between your application’s
>   Objective-C code and the YouTube player’s JavaScript code, thereby
>   allowing the iOS application to control the YouTube player. This
>   article describes the steps to install the library and get started
>   using it from your iOS application.

You're going to download the iOS youtube-helper library from [this Github repo](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper).